# Selecting folders by name and all files and containers in their childfolders with powershell?

Tags: powershell, copy, powershell-2.0

I have one big folder and I want to select 3 folders out of that and ALL items which are in these folders. I fail because I select everything with the name of the folder, so my script just copies the 3 empty folders.

that's what I have :

```
$folder = get-childitem "C:\bigfolder\" | where-Object {$_.name -eq "1" -or $_.name -eq "2" -or $_.name -eq "3"} | % {Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination C:\_archive\}
```

right now it just copies folder `1,2,3`  to my folder `C:\_archive`

I first tried to add `-recursive` but that doesn't change anything. I probably have to use something else than name...

Comment: Did you add -Recurse to Copy-Item scriptblock?

Comment: % {Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination C:\_archive\ -Recurse}

Comment: thanks man :) if you put that as answer i will accept and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the -Recurse in the Copy-Item scriptblock i.e:

```
% {Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination C:_archive\ -Recurse}
```